# SSIS Sql parameters logging

Tags: logging, error-handling, ssis

is there a way inside a sql server 2008 ssis package to automatically log parameters passed to stored procedures and/or command ? 
I'm trying to access those information from a script task linked to the global OnError event but it doesn't seem to be a reference to the current sql command, is there a general way to do this ? or do i have to implement custom logging for every sql command i'im firing ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that is associated to the `Execute SQL` task that can automatically handle this but that's not to say there aren't mechanisms for capturing this information. Could you provide a bit more information? Are the values for the parameters assigned or are they computed via expressions?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, I have a number of `Execute Process Tasks` defined in one of my projects. Each container has its own set of inputs and outputs that I wanted logged so my approach was to add an OnPostExecute event with a script task associated with it. There I fired information events to log the details of what happened in that task. This obviously presumes you've selected the OnInformation event to log.

```
        try
        {
            //User::ExecuteArgs,User::ExecuteError,User::ExecuteOutput
            string args = Dts.Variables["ExecuteArgs"].Value.ToString();
            string output = Dts.Variables["ExecuteOutput"].Value.ToString();
            string error = Dts.Variables["ExecuteError"].Value.ToString();
            bool fireAgain = false;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Post execute output", string.Format("Output: {0}", output), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            {
                Dts.Events.FireWarning(0, "Post execute error", string.Format("Error: {0}", error), string.Empty, 0);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args))
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Post execute args", string.Format("Args: {0}", args), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
            } 

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Dts.Events.FireWarning(0, "Post package execution", string.Format("Trouble accessing variables {0}", ex.ToString()), string.Empty, 0);

        }
```